# Searching between two views in Wpf C#

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

I have two views in SQL sever (vHato and vHatoList), what I want is to find the word I write in a text box
this is my code in WPF the first one has no problem; but when I add the last part it gives me "Syntax Error"

```
 var query = db.Database.SqlQuery<vHato>(
                    $"Select * From vHato Where ((HatoDate Between ('{dtFrom}') And ('{dtTo}'))" +
                    $" And (HatoFullName Like N'%{txtSearchBox.Text.Trim()}%' Or HatoNo Like " +
                    $"'%{txtSearchBox.Text.Trim()}%' Or HatoLocation Like N'%{txtSearchBox.Text.Trim()}%'))");
                var hato = query.ToList();
                DgHato.ItemsSource = hato;
```

the whole one

```
 var query = db.Database.SqlQuery<vHato>(
                    $"Select * From vHato Where ((HatoDate Between ('{dtFrom}') And ('{dtTo}'))" +
                    $" And (HatoFullName Like N'%{txtSearchBox.Text.Trim()}%' Or HatoNo Like " +
                    $"'%{txtSearchBox.Text.Trim()}%' Or HatoLocation Like N'%{txtSearchBox.Text.Trim()}%'" +
                    $" Or HatoNo In (Select HatoNo From vHatoList Where (HatoFullName Like N'%{txtSearchBox.Text.Trim()}%')))");
                var hato = query.ToList();
                DgHato.ItemsSource = hato;
```

Here's a diff, to make it easier to see the difference between these two queries.

[image]
[image]

Comment: the first query works good, but the second one gives me syntax error, anybody can help me

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a right round bracket `)` at the end of the query. The correspond left round bracket is the first bracket in your query after the `where` clause. `Select * From vHato Where (...)`

```
var query = db.Database.SqlQuery<vHato>(
    $"Select * From vHato Where ((HatoDate Between ('{dtFrom}') And ('{dtTo}'))" +
    $" And (HatoFullName Like N'%{txtSearchBox.Text.Trim()}%' Or HatoNo Like " +
    $"'%{txtSearchBox.Text.Trim()}%' Or HatoLocation Like N'%{txtSearchBox.Text.Trim()}%'" +
    $" Or HatoNo In (Select HatoNo From vHatoList Where (HatoFullName Like N'%{txtSearchBox.Text.Trim()}%'))))");
            var hato = query.ToList();
            DgHato.ItemsSource = hato;
```